# Empty $_POST after sending angular post request

Tags: angular, post, http-post

I am sending post request in angular

```
public saveLead(name: string, phone: string, text: string){
        const params: Lead = new Lead(name,phone,text);

        const headers = {
            'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        };

        return this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1/saveLead', params, {headers});
    }
```

but when I am checking $_POST on php side it is always empty

Comment: Can you log `params`? What's in it?

Comment: yes, in params I have Lead object    Lead {name: "ff", phone: "ff", text: "dd"}

Comment: try by changing `Content-Type` to json as: `'Content-Type':'application/json'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `HttpParams` to set your values

```
const body = new HttpParams()
  .set('name', 'foo')
  .set('phone', 'bar')
  .set('text', 'baz')
```

and that you send as body, `HttpClient` will take care of the headers

```
return this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1/saveLead', body)
```

Comment: Then it's not `x-www-form-urlencoded` what your API is expecting

Answer (score 0):

in your ts file:

```
public saveLead(name: string, phone: string, text: string){
    const params: Lead = new Lead(name,phone,text);
    return this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1/saveLead', params);
}
```

in your php:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
var_dump($data)
```

Comment: $data is NULL in this case